# I'm trying to make a form where the second select will be fetched from the backend according to the value selected from the first dropdown in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Here I however tried to make the second div visible if a value is selected in the first dropdown. But I want to make a form where there will be 3 dropdown but only the first will be visible where the user will select any value and the 2nd dropdown will be accordingly. I even need to fetch the values using API. Here's an example of the form what I'm trying to make : https://donate.alauddintrust.com Thanking you!

```
import React from 'react';
import Section2 from '../Sections/Section2'
 
class App1 extends React.Component {
 //set the statte default value
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: 'hide'};
  }
//   set the state value based on select option value
  divstatus = (e) =>{
     this.setState({value: e.target.value});
  }
  render() {
   
    return (
        <>
          <div className="container">
          <header class="page-header">
              <h1 className={['text-warning']}>Donate <i>Now</i></h1>
          </header>
          <form className="donation-form form-horizontal container" id="donation-form">
              <div id="donation-type-group" className="form-group">

                  <label htmlFor="recurrence">Donation Type <span className="required">*</span></label>

                  <select id="donation_type" onChange={this.divstatus} name="donation_type" className="form-control">
                      <option value="show">Select Donation Type</option>
                      <option value="hide">Sadaqa</option>
                      <option value="2">Fitrana</option>
                      <option value="3">Zakat</option>
                      <option value="4">Fidya</option>
                      <option value="5">Qurbani</option>
                      <option value="6">Donation</option>
                      <option value="15">Kaffara</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
              <div className={this.state.value}>
              <div id="donation-type-group" className={['form-group']}>
                  <label htmlFor="recurrence">Programs<span className="required">*</span></label>

                  <select id="donation_type" name="donation_type" className="form-control">
                      <option value="">Select Donation Type</option>
                      <option value="1">Sadaqa</option>
                      <option value="2">Fitrana</option>
                      <option value="3">Zakat</option>
                      <option value="4">Fidya</option>
                      <option value="5">Qurbani</option>
                      <option value="6">Donation</option>
                      <option value="15">Kaffara</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
              </div>
              <div class="text-center">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Submit donation</button>
              </div>
          </form>
          <hr/>
          <Section2 />
      </div>
      </>
  
)
};
}
export default App1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I did somthing similar a while ago, you can display the first dropdown and `onChange` of the first dropdown trigger the API call to update the state to hold the options for the second dropdown, and in the second dropdown section when the api results are empty dont render the second dropdown (could use a `(results) ?? <GoodComponent/>` will only show if results not empty)

could also add a loading state value to disable the dropdowns in between API calls and listen to its changes using a `useEffect` hook

Comment: Can you just share a website where I can get refrence from I have no idea how to do it. I'm a newbie to react.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56352115/react-how-to-populate-one-dropdowns-based-on-selection-from-another-dropdown-b

Comment: @AvaishAnsari if this answer helped you please accept it